# c++11 array passing to function error

Tags: c++, arrays, function, c++11

I am trying out a c++11 array by following along with [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czrbhZjp4JA&list=PL3345A50B73C26A6F) YouTube video tutorial series.  Though I am not very skilled in using my IDE's, I have both of my IDE's, Eclipse and Codeblocks, set to have the compiler follow the C++0x ISO language standard [-std=c++0x] which at least allows them to understand the syntax of a c++11 array, such as `array <double, 5> rainfall;`  Both are responding in the same way.  The following code I have written passes this array to a function which prints it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void printArray(double[], int);

int main()
{
    array <double, 5> rainfall;

    rainfall[0] = 2.3;
    rainfall[1] = 0.3;
    rainfall[2] = 0.0;
    rainfall[3] = 4.1;
    rainfall[4] = 0.5;

    printArray(rainfall, 5);

    return 0;
}

void printArray(double array[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " | ";
    }
}
```

With a non-c++11 array, such as `double rainfall[5]` this works fine, but with `array <double, 5> rainfall` there is an error which reads `cannot convert 'std::array<double, 5u>' to 'double*' for argument '1' to 'void printArray(double*, int)`  The video I am following uses the same code, yet does not receive this error.

Comment: Call the function as `printArray(rainfall.data(), 5);`. The [`data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) member function returns a pointer to the beginning of the underlying array. The `std::array` itself is not convertible to C style array, which is why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass `rainfall.data()` to the function. An `std::array<T, N>` is not implicitly convertible to `T[N]`.

Comment: `rainfall.begin()` will return an iterator that is not necessarily (convertible to) a `double *`. The OP needs to pass `rainfall.data()` to the function.

Comment: @Praetorian: Thanks, I didn't know about data

Answer (score 9):

As you can see, in the video you use, the guy uses a static, c-style array which can be implicitly converted to T* BUT you are using an c++11 array, which doesn't have implicit conversion to static array. Though, C++11's array class has method data which gives you direct access to the underlying data, which will do in your case.

But in this case, if you want to use the function with c++11 arrays, you can make an overload like this:

`template <typename T, size_t Size>
void printArray(const std::array<T, Size>& arr);`

This would work with any size and you don't need to pass another (unneeded) parameter for size ;)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can define the function as

```
void printArray (const array <double, 5>& myarray, int size)
```

Comment: Why do you need `int size` again if the declaration already has 5?

Comment: It is a parameter of the template. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: yes it has a `constexpr size_type size()` member function, so `printArray` doesn't need `int size` parameter

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I misunderstood you. The first function parameter is enough. I just kept it in order to maintain the same function body.